# Surface integral of curl

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals, divergence-operator, curl

Let $\vec F(x,y,z)=(x^2+y^2+\sin(xy)$, $e^x$+$2xy, -yz$). Calculate the flow of $\nabla\times\vec F$ through the following surface: 
$$
S=\{(x,y,z) x^2 + 2y^2 + 3z^2=10, y\ge 0\}
$$

I figured that if you added $S_{aux} =\{(x,y,z)\in \Bbb R^3 : x^2 + 3z^2 =10\}$ to S you had a closed surface and therefore could use the divergence theorem. This would mean that: 
$$
\iint_{S+S_{aux}}\nabla\times\vec F \mathrm{d}s = \iiint_{V} \nabla\circ(\nabla\times\vec F) \mathrm{d}v.
$$
Since $\nabla\circ(\nabla\times\vec F)=0$, then: 
$$
\iiint_{V} \nabla\circ(\nabla\times\vec F)\mathrm{d}v = 0.
$$
Therefore 
$$\iint_{S+S_{aux}}\nabla\times\vec F \mathrm{d}s = 0,
$$ 
and since 
$$\iint_{S+S_{aux}}\nabla\times\vec F \mathrm{d}s = \iint_S\nabla\times\vec F \mathrm{d}s + \iint_{S_{aux}}\nabla\times\vec F \mathrm{d}s = 0$$ we have $$\iint_S\nabla\times\vec F \mathrm{d}s = -\iint_{S_{aux}}\nabla\times\vec F \mathrm{d}s.
$$

Could you please tell me if my thinking is correct? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: $S=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+2y^2+3z^2=10,y≥10\}?$  If $y\ge10,$ then $x^2+3z^2\le -190$  Wait.  Reading further, maybe you meant $y\ge0?$

Comment: Couldn't you just use Stokes' theorem?

Comment: Yes, I meant y≥0. Thanks. Let me change that now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm certain that the point of the problem is to use Stokes' theorem.  $\partial S$ is the intersection of the plane $y=0$ with $S$ so it's the ellipse $x^2+3z^2=10, y=0.$  On this curve, $F$ simplifies to $(x^2, e^x, 0)$  When you compute the circulation of $F$ over $\partial S$ there will only be a contibution from the first coordinate.

Comment: I have just tried that by parametrizing the ellipse as $\alpha(\theta):(\sqrt{10}cos{\theta},0,\sqrt{\frac {10}3}sin{\theta})$, then calculated the line integral which ended up giving me zero as well. Does that mean that what I did was valid?

Comment: Yes, I think what you did was correct, but it's been a long time since I worked with this stuff, so I'm not certain.